# Flutter: SilverAppBar Background Image with Text

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make an app bar looks like this:

[image]

I hope to collapse the big image using `SilverAppBar`, but I am having hard time to insert `AssetImage` (or `Image.asset'). I almost exactly followed the code from the [official Flutter website][2], and unfortunately, both` AssetImage`and`Image.asset` cannot be used as shown below:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Image.asset with Container widget

```
          Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Image.asset('name'),
                    )
                    ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use background like this:

```
SliverAppBar(
...
...
   background: Image(
      image: NetworkImage(recipeDetails.coverPhoto),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add  [background_app_bar: ^1.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/background_app_bar/versions)
dependency.

```
import 'package:background_app_bar/background_app_bar.dart';
...

SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      pinned: true,
      snap: true, 
      floating: true,
      expandedHeight: 160.0,
      flexibleSpace: new BackgroundFlexibleSpaceBar(    // Add this
          title: new Text('title'),
          centerTitle: false,
          titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
          background: Image.asset('url'),
    ),
   ),
```